# Split a string from a JList

Tags: java

I am having problems spliting a line that I select from a JList.
Here is my code:

```
int index = list.getSelectedIndex();
String s = (String) list.getSelectedValue();            
String[] temp = s.split(" ");                         
System.out.println(temp[0]);
```

It doesn't show anything and I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

`s` has value `ID:3 Name:john Country:Italy Grade1:9 Grade2:7`

Comment: How does `s` looks like?

Comment: ID:3  Name:john  Country:Italy Grade1:9 Grade2:7

Comment: @user3421241 Why is this information in comment and not in question? You must know that not everyone read comments so if you have information relevant to question use [[edit]] option and add it to your post.

Comment: @user3421241 Do you have a space before `ID:3` ?

Comment: @user3421241 Perhaps your string doesn't contain what you think it does. What is printed if you add: `System.out.println("'" + s + "'");` to your code?

Comment: It's works fine,with the String that u have provided.May the String that you are getting may be wrong.Just check it first.

Comment: I have solved the problem, there was a space before ID. Thanks for your sugestions

Comment: next time i suggest using `trim()` to cut those bad spaces.

Comment: Thank you, I will follow your advice

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String[] temp = s.trim().split("\\s");
```

The parameter is regex. Check more about [String::split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) and [regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum).